# Alternating irreducibility of polynomial $t^n + t^{n-1} + \ldots + t + 1$?

Tags: galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I was doing a problem on Stewart's Galois Theory. In section 3, we were asked to decide the irreducibility or otherwise of the following polynomials:

> $t^4 + t^3 + t^2 + t + 1$
>
> $t^5 + t^4 + t^3 + t^2 + t + 1$
>
> $t^6 + t^5 + t^4 + t^3 + t^2 + t + 1$

After proving polynomials in this form with degree 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, I realize that, for $p(t) = t^n + t^{n-1} + \ldots + t + 1$, we have two cases:

1. If $n$ is odd, the polynomial is reducible with the factorization $t^n + t^{n-1} + \ldots + t + 1 = (t + 1)(t^{n-1} + t^{n-3} + \ldots + t^2 + 1)$.
2. If $n$ is even, then the polynomial $p(t) = t^n + t^{n-1} + \ldots + t + 1$ is irreducible if and only if $p(t+1)$ is irreducible. Then, substituting $t$ with $t+1$, $p(t + 1) = a_n t^n + a_{n-1} t^{n-1} + \ldots + a_{1}$, where the coefficient $a_i$ is the $(n+ 1 - i)$-th item in the $(n+1)$-th row of Pascal's Triangle.
   For example:  when $n = 4$, $p(t+1) = t^4 + 5t^3 + 10t^2 + 10t + 5$. Thus we could use Eisenstein's Criterion and let the prime $q = n+1$ or in this example, $q = 5$, such that the irreducibility of $p(t)$ immediately follows.

This alternating pattern of irreducibility looks very fascinating to me but I have no idea why it is this. What is, if there is any, the deep idea behind this? Why the (ir)reducibility depends on the parity of the degree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C. Falcon’s response was just on the mark, but there’s something even deeper going on here.

In fact, it makes more sense to look at the polynomials $X^n-1$, which always have a factor $X-1$, and no others if $n$ is prime, but the general fact is this:
$$
X^n-1=\prod_{d|n}\Phi_d(X)\,,
$$
the $\Bbb Z$-polynomials $\Phi_d$ being the *cyclotomic* polynomials mentioned in Falcon’s answer. These start out with $\Phi_1(X)=X-1$, $\Phi_2(X)=X+1$, and $\Phi_3(X)=X^2+X+1$. Using the Möbius Inversion Formula, you may prove that
$$
\Phi_m(X)=\prod_{d|m}\bigl(X^d-1\bigr)^{\mu(m/d)}\,,
$$
where $\mu$ is the *Möbius function*, which I’ll give you the pleasure of finding out about.

Comment: Wow the Mobius function is indeed really cool. Thank you so much for your insight!

Answer (score 4):

One has: $$t^8+t^7+t^6+t^5+t^4+t^3+t^2+t+1=\left(t^2+t+1\right)\left(t^6+t^3+1\right).$$
Hence, $t^8+t^7+t^6+t^5+t^4+t^3+t^2+t+1$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ and your conjecture is false.

However, your argument is perfectly fine when $n+1$ is a prime number (notice that it's not always the case) and in this very case you are dealing with [cyclotomic polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial) of prime order.

Comment: wow thanks for catching that! That's really cool! Thanks for the reference also.